# PostgreSQL - Need a way to return all results

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently, this query only returns cases where there is a value in my "SFDC Contact ID" column.  Curious how I can change the query to return all results?  I assume this would need to be an outer join?

```
SELECT cmsuser.userid as "User ID", cmsuser.username as "Username", cmsuserprofile.value as "SFDC Contact ID"
FROM cmsuser, cmsuserprofile 
WHERE cmsuser.userid = cmsuserprofile.userid and fieldid = '5004';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like:

```
         SELECT cmsuser.userid as "User ID", 
                cmsuser.username as "Username", 
                cmsuserprofile.value as "SFDC Contact ID"
           FROM cmsuser
LEFT OUTER JOIN cmsuserprofile 
             ON cmsuser.userid = cmsuserprofile.userid 
           WHERE fieldid = '5004';
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will return all records from the `cmsuser` (the table on the left side of the join) even if there is no match on the `cmsuserprofile`.

It's a good practice to separate `JOIN` and `WHERE` conditions to make your code more easy to understand and maintain, in this way it's easier to get where you have a join condition and what is just a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `fieldid` is in the profile table.  And, by "all results" you mean "all users".  If so, then you do want a `left join` like this:

```
SELECT u.userid as "User ID", u.username as "Username",
       p.value as "SFDC Contact ID"
FROM cmsuser u LEFT JOIN
     cmsuserprofile p
     ON u.userid = p.userid and p.fieldid = '5004';
```

Note:  you should use proper explicit `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.